# Can we factor "tag" in "a single tag or a group of tags"

Tags: phrase-usage, plural-forms

In sentence I made

> the user identifies the range of nodes which are affected by single or a group of tags

Is it acceptable to say "by single or a group of **tags**" which means "by  single **tag** or a group of **tags**"?

I mean how can I factor out the "tag" in this phrase and if "by single or group of tags" is a grammatical phrase or not?

---

**Update:** it is suggested to use "a" before single and say "a single tag or a group of tags". 
But how do you justify the big number of results (more than 3 million results) for [the phrase "by single or group of " in Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20anchor&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22by%20single%20or%20group%20of%22)?

Comment: Can you write a complete example sentence?

Comment: Ahmad. Please provide more context. I don't understand what you're asking, nor do I have context to base a guess upon!

Comment: @pazzo I did and example.

Comment: Just write *by a single tag or a group of tags.* Your version is **four letters** shorter, not very natural, and open to misunderstanding.

Comment: Many of those Google returns you got are written in really bad English, including this one, [which uses terrible English](http://www.eva-designs.com/things-to-consider-when-designing-a-website/). Many other returns from your search are from India and Thailand, etc., not known for the greatest English.

Comment: @pazzo you want to say "single or group of somethins" is not common in standard English ? By the way, I think my question is clear. what is unclear about it? Some people vote to close it as it's unclear!!

Comment: It is not clear whether the prepositional phrase (by ...) goes with "affected" (affected by...) or if it goes with "identify" (identify by).  Part of the problem is that the prepositional phrase  "by single or a group of tags' is malformed.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to write out both *tag* and tags*.

> ...by a single or a group of tags.

This could lead to confusion, the reader could wonder *What is 'a single'?*.

Writing them both out makes your sentences clear, unambiguous and more pleasant to read.

> ...by a single tag or a group of tags.

Note that I also added the indefinite article *a*. I'm not sure why you left it out, but I doubt it can be missed in this sentence.

Comment: Thank you, actually I myself didn't know I should use "a" before "single" and thought it itself means "a"! interestingly I found many such phrases in google. I mean [by single or group of](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+anchor&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22by+single+or+group+of%22)"

Comment: Aha, perhaps that it can be left out then, but if you leave it out then you should do the same with *a group of*. Either let them both take an article or let neither have one.